# If app_metadata isActive == true redirect user to /dashbaord if not /signup

Tags: auth0, next-auth

I would like to achieve below using an ACTION FLOW.

If app_metadata `isActive == true` redirect user to `/dashbaord` if not `/signup`

But, I need to be able to use `session.user.email` inside my app too. For an example, when the user is redirected to `/signup`, I still need to be able to access the `session.user.email` using my apps’ javascript code (next.js app using next-auth)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could expose `isActive` in the user's JWT, and your app could check that.

Comment: Yes I can do it in the app and that is how it's being done at the moment. But I would prefer this could be handled on Auth0's end, that way I can easily lock down routes in my app from my next-auth middleware.

Comment: Redirecation from within Action is designed to add additional steps to your login flow. If you want to redirect user to dashboard, the login flow is still active and you might get errors when user has to login again. Maybe you could check the metadata and if user is active redirect to dashboard using the returnUrl in /authorize call and if not, redirect to sign-up as an additional login-flow step, then return user from the /signup page back to Auth0 login flow using /redirect endpoint with state parameter? After successful signup your would be redirected to /dashboard as specified in returnUrl